# adding a links to my banner images in a banner rotator code

Tags: php, hyperlink, rotator

I've searched but the results I found weren't useful to my case.

I have this code that shows rotating banners on my page. It pulls images from a folder and I can add more images through admin.
I would like to make those images clickable, so they can take you to a page on my site.
I don't know PHP, but I can copy paste well and do have some logic.
I would appreciate if you could modify the existing code, so that it works.

Thank you

```
<div class="baner">
            <div class="baner_icon">
            </div>
            <div id="rotator">
                <ul>
                    <?php 
                    $baners = TopBaners::model()->recently()->findAll();
                    $i = 0;
                      foreach ($baners as $value) {
                        if ($i == 0) {
                            ?><li class="show"><img src="/i/<?php echo $value->file ?>" width="999" height="300px" alt="IMG"></li><?PHP
                        } else {
                            ?><li><img src="/i/<?php echo $value->file ?>" height="300px" width="999" alt="IMG"></li><?PHP
                        }
                        $i++;
                      }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `I don't know php :( , but i can copy paste well`: then you came to the wrong place.

Comment: see the answer, but it will be  the best for you to learn php.

Comment: You'd need to know the structure of your `TopBaners` module. You can try to do this by **briefly** adding `print '<pre>'; print_r($value); print '</pre>';` as a new line after `if ($i == 0) {` and seeing what appears on the page. Then we have to understand how the model is loaded (from a directory?) and we have to figure out a way of supplying extra information, i.e., the *href* you want to link to. Unless it's always the same link for all banners, in which case Muhammet's answer is enough... and you also do not know HTML in addition to PHP, so you've got two things you'd better learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="baner">
        <div class="baner_icon">
        </div>
        <div id="rotator">
            <ul>
                <?php 
                $baners = TopBaners::model()->recently()->findAll();
                $i = 0;
                  foreach ($baners as $value) {
                    if ($i == 0) {
                        ?><a href = "YOUR LINK"><li class="show"><img src="/i/<?php echo $value->file ?>" width="999" height="300px" alt="IMG"></li></a><?PHP
                    } else {
                        ?><a href = "YOUR LINK"><li><img src="/i/<?php echo $value->file ?>" height="300px" width="999" alt="IMG"></li></a><?PHP
                    }
                    $i++;
                  }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for quick reply!
I know HTML, but PHP just enough not to mess things up and be able to tweak with code :)
Iserni->after i added your code, everythings still looks OK.
Muhammad-> i do need a separate link for each image, not one for all.

Comment: OK, i'm was wrong, now the site displays TopBaners Object code
if that helps :)
http://khisam.com/ru/index

Comment: i don't know javascript good, so you might want to post this as a seperate javascript question.

Comment: Muhammet, but isn't it all in php?